# What is a suitable power supply for a 2x ATI Cards in Crossfire Configuration?

Tags: power-supply, amd-radeon, crossfire

Making the assumption of a standard PC with standard parts and yes, I know there are PSU Calculators, but I'm talking brand names that are good and reliable.

Cheapest possible please!

I want to run say 2 ATI Radeon 5770's in crossfire for a system I want to offer for sale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're running crossfire on a 57xx series, the GPU's are quite low power (in comparison to 48xx series and nvidia GPU's)

so corsair's value range should be fine (VX series if they do them in the required power range), antec, Enermax and OCZ all make decent PSU's too

[this article page](http://www.bit-tech.net/hardware/graphics/2009/11/24/multi-gpu-round-up/8) has a power consumption chart for ati crossfire cards.

as has been said, go for an 80+ certified and you should be fine (most efficient at 80% of maximum load)

Answer (score 1):

... Lucky ***! (Wish I had those cards... and time for gaming!)

Anyway, jealousy aside, [According to the specification page](http://www.amd.com/us/products/desktop/graphics/ati-radeon-hd-5000/hd-5770/Pages/ati-radeon-hd-5770-system-requirements.aspx):

> 450 Watt or greater power supply with
>   one 75W 6-pin PCI Express® power
>   connectors recommended (600 Watt and
>   two 6-pin connectors for ATI
>   CrossFireX™ technology in dual mode)

Comment: Well, lucky is the person who buys the system, so, whats a good brand for a power supply that provides that power? (As, pretty much all of them do)

Comment: I just had a client who bought an expensive 1000w PSU and it failed after 9 months... There is no good one, you just sometimes get lucky! If going for over 550w, I would personally recommend getting a 80%+certified one as it cuts down on power costs, apart from that, just make sure it has a good warranty.

Comment: Thanks for the information :) it will definately help when someone can actually afford that systemL its only $2000... Hehe.. Only.... :S